# What RPG game engine in JavaScript could I use?

Tags: html5, rpg

I am trying to build an RPG using `HTML5/JavaScript`. Can anyone point out a few game engines for developing RPG in JavaScript

Comment: Let me rephrase the question!

When is an external engine/framework necessary for building an html game.If I have two armies and each of the person in that army has health/attack/defense , visually pleasing environment , but not much environmental movement , hitTests , is it necessary to adopt an engine/framework?

Comment: Edit your question and make it less vague.

Comment: I think that you should always try to find some framework that suits your needs, it can save you dozen of hours of work total.

The No framework path: Better for learning how to really program games.

Using Framework: for delivering a better product at the end of the project.

Comment: Harsha, your question is being down-voted because it's not a good fit for the site. Even with your rephrasing in your comment. The problem is there's not *correct* answer. To use an engine or not is a decision you have to make, and which one to use is also up to you. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) about what types of questions to ask here.

Comment: "Please give me resources on how to make (broad category of stuff) in (common programming language)." is 1. not a question and 2. *waaaaay* too broad, sorry.

Comment: I didn't ask for resources or any kind of coding help.I am new to frameworks and just wanted to see what options were.I guess you guys could have at the very least refrained from down voting!Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search lead me to the page below, where you can find a list of JS game engines. While not every engine on the list is specifically designed for RPGs, you should be able to quickly determine which engines may fit your needs.

https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines